# Two Spring Service Beans with same Class Name (different package) are throwing Error even with qualifier

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following...

```
package package1;

@Service
@Qualifier("kb")
public class UserService {
...
}

package package2;

@Service
@Qualifier("user")
public class UserService {
...
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("user")
package2.UserService p2;
@Autowired
@Qualifier("kb")
package1.UserService p1;
```

But when I try to run this I get...

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [boot.Application]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'userService' for bean class [package1.UserService] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [package2.UserService]

How do I have 2 Services with the same name?

Answer (score 6):

Remove @Qualifier from class, use @Qualifier while autowiring only

```
@Service("kb")
public class UserService {
...
}

package package2;

@Service("user")
public class UserService {
...
}
```

From @Qualifier javadoc

```
**
 * This annotation may be used on a field or parameter as a qualifier for
 * candidate beans when autowiring. It may also be used to annotate other
 * custom annotations that can then in turn be used as qualifiers.
 */
```

Comment: Sorry had to take away the check I thought I had it working but now it is saying... `Consider defining a bean of type 'package1.UserService' in your configuration.`

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand the purpose of @Qualifier here.

> There may be a situation when you create more than one bean of the
>   same type and want to wire only one of them with a property. In such
>   cases, you can use the @Qualifier annotation along with @Autowired to
>   remove the confusion by specifying which exact bean will be wired.

What you are trying is to create 2 classes with the same name but in different packages. In order to do that you will need to specify the service's name as a value parameter to the @Service annotation in order to differentiate the two:

```
package package1;

@Service("kb")
public class UserService {
...
}

package package2;

@Service("user")
public class UserService {
...
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("user")
package2.UserService p2;
@Autowired
@Qualifier("kb")
package1.UserService p1;
```

Comment: Working for me with a similar test setup. What error are you getting ?

Comment: It says it can't find the other Service Let me try with a more simple project

Comment: It seems the simple project works but still not mine :-(

Comment: Please share the stacktrace and can you list the versions of the spring libraries you are using coz it is really hard to debug with such limited information.

Comment: what I don't like about Spring in this case is, treating two different classes as the same type just by looking at their "simple name"s instead of using the corresponding fully-qualified class names (i.e. considering the package name). Using the `@Qualifier` should only be required when we create more than one bean of the same fully-qualified class